# docker with asp.net core error dockerfile run dotnet publish

Tags: docker, asp.net-core

when i use docker build i receive this error: [error image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Qw8Yp.png)

i've change the relative path on docker file to absolute path changing `--from=build-env` to `bin/Release/netcoreapp3.1/publish/` but when i use docker-compose the error show again

Dockerfile

```
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/core/sdk:3.1 AS build-env
WORKDIR /app

# Copy csproj and restore as distinct layers
COPY *.csproj ./
RUN dotnet restore

# Copy everything else and build
COPY . ./
RUN dotnet publish -c Release -o out

# Build runtime image
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/core/aspnet:3.1
WORKDIR /app
COPY --from=build-env /app/out .
ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "SmartSchool.WebAPI.dll"]
```

docker-compose

```
version: "3.8"

volumes:
    SmartSchoolDb:

networks:
    mysqlNET:
    smartschoolNET:

services:

    mysql:
        image: "mysql:5.7"
        container_name: mysql
        ports:
            - "3306:3306"
        volumes:
            - SmartSchoolDb:/var/lib/mysql
        networks:
            - mysqlNET
        environment:
            - MYSQL_USER=root
            - MYSQL_PASSWORD=test
            - MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=test
            - MYSQL_ROOT_HOST=%
            - bind-address:0.0.0.0

    smartschool:
        build:
            context: .
            dockerfile: Dockerfile
        container_name: smart
        networks:
            - mysqlNET
            - smartschoolNET
        ports:
            - 5000:80
        environment:
            - DBHOST=mysql
        depends_on:
            - mysql
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I add .dockerignore created using vscode command `ctrl + shift + p` and `docker: add docker files to workspace`

i used this .dockerignore below

```
**/.classpath
**/.dockerignore
**/.env
**/.git
**/.gitignore
**/.project
**/.settings
**/.toolstarget
**/.vs
**/.vscode
**/*.*proj.user
**/*.dbmdl
**/*.jfm
**/azds.yaml
**/bin
**/charts
**/docker-compose*
**/Dockerfile*
**/node_modules
**/npm-debug.log
**/obj
**/secrets.dev.yaml
**/values.dev.yaml
README.md
bin/
obj/
out/
TestResults/
```